# Django : Pass a prefetch_related _set.all() in Ajax Search results

Tags: django, ajax, set, prefetch

I've implemented a table search product with Ajax and it works well.

But now, I want to build dynamically my table taking in account the number of my warehouses can be increase.

**search.js**

```
data.forEach((item) => {

                        const newName = (item.nom).slice(0, 30) + "...";
                        tableBody.innerHTML += `
                        <tr>
                            <th><a href="{% url 'product-update' ${item.id} %}">${item.sku}</a></th>
                            <td>${item.etat__etat}</td>
                            <td class="small">${newName}</td>
                            <td>${item.famille__nom}</td>
                            <td>${item.mageid}</td>
                            <td>${item.adresse}</td>
```

**models.py** (model for witch I need a set)

```
class SstStock(models.Model):
    warehouse = models.ForeignKey(Warehouse, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Produit)
    qty = models.IntegerField()
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

**views.py**

```
def search_product2(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search_str = json.loads(request.body).get('searchText')
        products = Produit.objects.filter(sku__icontains=search_str) | Produit.objects.filter(
            nom__icontains=search_str) | Produit.objects.filter(mageid__icontains=search_str)

        data = products.values(
            'id',
            'sku',
            'nom',
            
            [...]

            'sststock',

            [...]
            'cau_cli',
            'maxsst2',
        )

        return JsonResponse(list(data), safe=False)
```

Directly in template I could do :

**template**

```
{% for produit in produits %}
    {{ produit.sku}}<br>
    {% for sst in produit.sststock_set.all %}
    <span>{{sst.warehouse.code}} - {{ sst.qty }}</span><br>
    {% endfor %}
    <br>
{% endfor %}
```

But I couldn't find the way to pass the the sststock_set.all() in the JsonResponse. I got well a "sststock" value in it but it contains only the last value of the set instead of an array/dict of the whole set.

**console.log()**

```
qty: 7
sku: "ACP863"
sststock: 68095
```

68095 is the last ID of my set.
Worse, when I try to get item.sststock in the ForEach product, in my JS, it returns **Undefined**.

Any idea please ?

Comment: This is one of the (many) reasons why you should use a serializer, and *not* use `.values(...)`: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/over-use-of-values.html#extra-tips

Comment: I had heard about serializers but I'm really young at Python and I didn't dig this subject yet. It's clear this is the time for doing it. Thanks

Comment: Serializer are really simple to use and powerfull. But I still have the issue about my prefetch _set that is not present in the response. 
Other issue, how can I get a related field of one filed (foreignkey): eg: supplier__name or supplier.name instead of ID. Despite a __str__ in my model that asks to consider the NAME, it still got an ID. I tried to add a FIELDS list in the  serialize() ... no success

Comment: One response about related fields names instead of ID's . Django Doc [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.0/topics/serialization/#serialization-of-natural-keys)  . Add def natural_key(self) and set what Value you want serializer to retur. Don't forget to add **use_natural_foreign_keys=True** when you serialize your objects : data = serialize('json', (products), use_natural_foreign_keys=True)

Answer (score 0):

Found the way to apply @WillemVanOnsem advice with serializer.

Before all, my first error war to apply ManyToMany instead of ForeignKey on:

```
product = models.ManyToManyField(Produit)
```

After, I have set a serializer that retrieves the different stocks (warehouse_id + qty) and adds it to the Product model (with "source" parameter):

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Produit, SstStock


class StockSearchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SstStock
        fields = '__all__'
        fields = ['warehouse_id', 'qty']


class ProductSearchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    sststock = StockSearchSerializer(source='sststock_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Produit
        fields = '__all__'
```

To finish, I use the serializer with "many=True" in the view and return its result that will be handled by JS on my search page:

**views.py**

```
def search_product(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search_str = json.loads(request.body).get('searchText')
        products = Produit.objects.prefetch_related(
            Prefetch('sststock_set',
                     SstStock.objects.select_related('warehouse'))
                     ).filter(sku__icontains=search_str) | Produit.objects.filter(
            nom__icontains=search_str) | 
            Produit.objects.filter(mageid__icontains=search_str)
        
        serializer = ProductSearchSerializer(products, many=True)
        data = serializer.data
        return JsonResponse(list(data), safe=False)
```

And as wished, stocks array is added in the json response

[image]